# Why does this function call `UseMethod` after `return`?

Tags: r, oop, vctrs

Here's the body of `vctrs::vec_cast`:

```r
function (x, to, ..., x_arg = "", to_arg = "") 
{
    if (!missing(...)) {
        check_ptype2_dots_empty(...)
    }
    return(.Call(vctrs_cast, x, to, x_arg, to_arg))
    UseMethod("vec_cast", to)
}
<bytecode: 0x7f8f431528f0>
<environment: namespace:vctrs>
```

There's a call to `UseMethod`. But it's **after** the line which returns from the function. What deep magic is this?

Comment: The `UseMethod` just looks like some code that was accidently left in during [this change](https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/commit/b2e721bc96f519eec8c19b072ca7a91aac0bd1e1) where they moved the implementation of the function from the R world to the C world.  It will never actually be called.